# Using the progress bar for RSA key generation

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, rsa

How to make the progress bar for RSA key generation in the Windows forms app?

I have no idea how to do this or how to formulate the question correctly to search the internet. I tried to find some solutions but I didn't succeed.

```cs
var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
var priv_rsa_key = csp.ExportParameters(true);
var pub_rsa_key = csp.ExportParameters(false);
var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();

var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
xs.Serialize(sw, pub_rsa_key);
string rsa_key = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: That depends on how you're doing this key generation, doesn't it. Always provide code.

Comment: I understand. I will edit the question.

Comment: You need a count and a loop in order to show progress.  If you don't have that, and this is a time consuming function, set the ProgressBar to marquee style.